# Duplicate libraries in Windows Phone 8 upgrade

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I am upgrading an application from Windows Phone 7.1 to Windows Phone 8. every instance of the PanaromaItem and Pivot control gives me this error:

The type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Pivot' exists in both 'd:\Lib\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Phone.dll'

The xmlns reads:

```
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
```

What should that be in order for me to get rid of the reference to Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll?

Comment: Are you referencing `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll` from the `d:\lib` folder in the project?

Comment: Yes. Why do I have to type 15 characters just to say yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the second in the known upgrade issues listed @

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207030(v=vs.105).aspx.

Hope it helps!